# Accessing Shared memory in EL1 when Privilege Access Never (PAN) is Enabled

Tags: arm

With ARM Privilege Access Never Flag (PAN) [1](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0595/b/aarch64-system-registers/pan) enabled in EL1 , I was wondering, if EL1 upon taking an exception from EL0, EL1 will have to always disable PAN in order to use any shared memory between EL1 and EL0, that was created by EL1 and mapped into the EL0 address space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PAN bit enabled in EL1, it appears that any Virtual Address of EL0 accessed at EL1 shall Fault. Therefore, we need to disable PAN only for cases when EL1 shall be accessing user memory Virtual Address that is also mapped in EL1.